# Regeneration implementation for ppt content generation

Tags: python, large-language-model

We developed a code for ppt content generation where we get in json form as separate slides as array it contains title and content  using the GPT-3.5-turbo-16k model from Azure OpenAI. Now we need to regenerate content which is already generated where we need to provide regenerate button for each and every slide. We provide prompts for each regeneration to happen. What is the best solution for executing this as it is single slide regeneration option?

Don't have much idea how to proceed with this. So please help me with this.